# Updating state as an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm stuck trying to set the values for the variable `domainRecordsInput`, as they're dynamic. Sometimes there's one or two rows of data, sometimes there's six or eight. I need to update specific fields in the right object in an array.

This is as far as I've gotten:

[image]

```js
  function DomainRecordsTable() {
    const [records, setRecords] = useState(['']);

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOMAIN_RECORDS, {
      variables: {
        domain: domain,
      },
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      if (data && data.getDomainRecords) {
        setRecords( data.getDomainRecords.host );
      }
    }, [data]);

    const [exeRecords] = useMutation(SET_DOMAIN_RECORDS, {
      variables: {
        domain: domain,
        domainRecordsInput: [{
          hostName: "lol",
          recordType: "lol",
          address: "lol",
          mxPref: "lol",
          ttl: "lol",
        }]
      },
    });

    if (loading) return <LoadingIndicator />;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

    return (
      <>

      <TableComp>
        <Table.Head>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.Cell>
              <span>type</span>
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              <span>address</span>
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              <span>value</span>
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              <span>priority</span>
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              <span>ttl</span>
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              <span>actions</span>
            </Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Head>

        <Table.Body>
          {data.getDomainRecords.host.map((e, i) => (
            <Table.Row key={i}>
              <Table.Cell>
                <EasyEdit
                  type="text"
                  value={e.type}
                  onSave={(value) => setRecords((records) => ({ ...records[i], type: value }))}
                />
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <EasyEdit
                  type="text"
                  value={e.address}
                  onSave={(value) => setRecords((records) => ({ ...records[i], address: value }))}
                />
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell truncate={true} align="left">
                <EasyEdit
                  type="text"
                  value={e.name}
                  onSave={(value) => setRecords((records) => ({ ...records[i], name: value }))}
                />
              </Table.Cell>
              {e.type === "MX" ? (
                <Table.Cell align="right">
                  <EasyEdit
                    type="text"
                    value={e.mxPref}
                    onSave={(value) => setRecords((records) => ({ ...records[i], mxPref: value }))}
                  />
                </Table.Cell>
              ) : (
                <Table.Cell></Table.Cell>
              )}
              <Table.Cell>
                <EasyEdit
                  type="text"
                  value={e.ttl}
                  onSave={(value) => setRecords((records) => ({ ...records[i], ttl: value }))}
                />
              </Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>
                <button>delete row</button>
              </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
          ))}
        </Table.Body>
      </TableComp>

      <button>add row</button>

      </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I found to work for me:

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState([""]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data && data.getDomainRecords) {
    setRecords(data.getDomainRecords.host);
  }
}, [data]);

const updateItem = (prop, event, index) => {
  const old = records[index];
  const updated = { ...old, [prop]: event };
  const clone = [...records];
  clone[index] = updated;
  setRecords(clone);
};

const [exeRecords, { data: datalol }] = useMutation(SET_DOMAIN_RECORDS, {
  variables: {
    domain: domain,
    domainRecordInput: records.flatMap((e) => [
      {
        hostName: e.name,
        recordType: e.type,
        address: e.address,
        mxPref: e.mxPref,
        ttl: e.ttl,
      },
    ]),
  },
});

...

onSave={(e) => updateItem("ttl", e, i)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` with an object.

Note: untested but something like this

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState({
          hostName: "",
          recordType: "",
          address: "",
          mxPref: "",
          ttl: "",
        });

...

onSave={() => setRecords(records => ({...records, hostName: e.target.value}))
```

If you need array, use `Object.keys(records)` or `Object.values(records)` to convert.

Comment: @gfylol Do you mean when you edit `type` then `name` for example, then `type` will be replaced by `name`?

Comment: Could be that it's not setting properly because in `[0]`, seems like `record` is not updated. Can you `console.log` to make sure that each field is set correctly?